# CMMotionActivity Battery Consumption

Tags: ios, swift, cmmotionmanager

I'm developing an app where I need to detect motion activity changes with accuracy. I'm thinking of two approaches:

1. Keep the CMMotionActivity active all the time;
2. Start/Stop the CMMotionActivity in periods of 30 seconds.

Do you know which of this approaches will be more efficient regarding battery consumption?